# Conversion from Phone axis to world coordinate axis

Tags: android, math, geometry

I am working on a project where i want to convert my android phones axis onto the world coordinate axis. I have the acceleration along the phones 3 axis (x,y,z) and the three angles being the azimuth,pitch and roll. How can i proceed in virtually converting my phones axis to the world coordinate axis(truenorth,trueeast).
As far as i am doing is giving me wrong result. 
This is my approach.

Lets say 
-0.030029837    -0.008528218    -0.199289320 is the Acceleration along phone's X,Y,Z axis and
0.01618620  0.48581530  0.19617330 are the three angles(in radians) being the azimuth, pitch and roll.

To get the acceleration along the "truenorth" i am simply taking the acceleration along Y axis and multiplying it with cos of all the three angles ie.
-0.008528218*cos(0.19617330)*cos(0.48581530)*cos(0.01618620)=-0.00739584

To get the acceleration along the "trueeast" i am simply taking the acceleration along X axis and multiplying it with cos of all the three angles ie.
-0.030029837*cos(0.19617330)*cos(0.48581530)*cos(0.01618620)=-0.026042471

To get the acceleration along the "vertical upwards" i am simply taking the acceleration along Z axis and multiplying it with cos of the 2  angles ie.
-0.199289320*cos(0.19617330)*cos(0.48581530)=-0.172850298

Now to check whether i have done it correct or wrong. I did a consistency test.
The magnitude of acceleration along phone's X,Y,Z axis should be equal to the magnitude of acceleration along the trueeast, truenorth and the vertically upwards.
But this is coming to not equal.

0.20 is not equal to 0.17

Where am i going wrong? It would be of a great help if someone out there could help me out.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your azimuth, pitch and roll angles represent how much angle the phone axes deviate with respect to world axes. If my assumption is right then the following lines of code will fulfill your needs.

```
    float yaw = (float) Math.toDegrees(0.01618620);
    float pitch = (float) Math.toDegrees(0.48581530);
    float roll = (float) Math.toDegrees(0.19617330);
    float acc[] = { -0.030029837f, -0.008528218f, -0.199289320f, 1 };

    float[] matrix = new float[16];
    Matrix.setIdentityM(matrix, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(matrix, 0, yaw, 0, 0, 1);
    Matrix.rotateM(matrix, 0, pitch, 0, 1, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(matrix, 0, roll, 1, 0, 0);

    float accT[] = new float[4];
    Matrix.multiplyMV(accT, 0, matrix, 0, acc, 0);

    float rawMagnitude = Matrix.length(acc[0], acc[1], acc[2]);
    System.out.println(rawMagnitude);
    float transformedMagnitude = Matrix.length(accT[0], accT[1], accT[2]);
    System.out.println(transformedMagnitude);
```

The console printed magnitudes are

```
    0.2017195
    0.20171948
```

I used [android.opengl.Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html). The static methods used here are self explanatory for more details see the API documentation.

If my assumption is exactly opposite, that is, if your azimuth, pitch and roll angles represent how much angle the world axes deviate with respect to phone axes, then just make your azimuth, pitch and roll angles negative.